# GIT Branch Work Flow

Tags: git, github, versioning

Working in a large group project this is our work flow:

```
 // create branch
 git checkout -b mybranch
 (do work)
 // commit to branch locally
 git commit -a
 // push to remote
 git push origin mybranch
 (repeat)
```

When done with working in our branch we merge the branch into master:

```
 // go to master
 git checkout master     
 // update
 git pull master
 // merge our branch into master
 git merge mybranch
 (solve conflicts)
 git push
```

Now we just repeat the above steps and work flow was fine for a few days.  Now suddenly everyone is getting non-forward updates on other group members branches and master.  For example someone git pulled within master, then merged but they cannot push.  It says non-fast-forward push.  This is very odd as it says master is completely up to date.

The following is immediately after a git pull, git merge mybranch, git push:

```
  ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:foo/project.git'
  To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
  Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
  'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Yet a git pull says we are up to date.

So the question is, what is the expected workflow for a large group within GIT?  How should we be dealing with the branching mechanism.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There was no problem with your previous workflow.

You pull in new changes, merge your branches together, and then push out the merged result. At your option, you may use `rebase` instead of `merge` for changes which were never made public.

The issue here is likely that someone rewrote history in their local copy; if that happens, you'll be "up to date" - as in, your working copy is identical to the remote end - but you won't be able to push.

If you do a fresh clone of the repository, and from there do a `merge` and `push`, it will probably succeed.

Comment: Why re-clone when you can git checkout master; git reset --hard origin/master?

Comment: @chazomaticus I have no idea what was done to their local repository. For all we know, `origin` has meant two different things. A fresh start is clean and unambiguous.

Comment: Borealid is probably right about history being rewritten because of e.g.. rebase. I just want to add that I'd keep my branches local and not push them to origin because origin will be spammed with a lot of unecessary 'mybranch', unless mybranch has to be shared with others, keep it local.